# jQuery - Add class to the next section, when all first fields (input, radio, select, textarea) are filled

Tags: jquery, forms

I make a multi-step form.

I would like to add `class="active"` into the second `<section>` when all fields in the first section are filled. In the same way, I will activate third section when the first and second fields are all filled. (Not accordion but remaining the first section shown.)
I will active the next sections to show/hide by css.

I have tried to find the best examples to apply but I couldn't find the best one yet.

I am not good at jQuery and javascript, even though I can build HTML and CSS.

https://codepen.io/jandspace/pen/jOOXWzL

```
<form>
    <section id="ONE" class="section one active">
        <h2>Secion 1</h2>
        <div class="field-container">
            City: <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Full Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Transport:
            <select class="required" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>selected a value</option>
                <option>Car</option>
                <option>Buss</option>
                <option>Train</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Payment?
            <input type="radio" id="yes" name="testRadio" class="required" required /> Yes
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="testRadio" class="required" /> No
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Message:
            <textarea name="description" class="required"></textarea>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="TWO" class="section two">
        <h2>Secion 2</h2>
        <div class="field-container">
            Animal:
            <select class="required" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>selected a value</option>
                <option>Lion</option>
                <option>Rebbit</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Edible?
            <input type="radio" id="yes" name="testRadio" class="required" required /> Yes
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="testRadio" class="required" /> No
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="THREE" class="section three">
        <h2>Secion 3</h2>
        <div class="field-container">
            Name: <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Email: <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Email" required />
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Are you okay?
            <select class="required" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>selected a value</option>
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            When?
            <input type="checkbox" name="when1" value="Day"> Day
            <input type="checkbox" name="when2" value="Car"> Night
            <input type="checkbox" name="when3" value="Any"> Anytime<br>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            <input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="human" class="required"> I agree to the terms.<br>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="SUBMIT" class="section submit">
        <button type="button">Submit</button>
    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use ``.on('blur')`` event to check if all fields are filled or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am validating all the fields on out focus of text area and done it for section two.Similarly you can do it for section three.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        form {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 8px solid orange;
}
section {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.field-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.section {
  opacity: 0.25;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}
.section.active {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
.section.submit {
  background: orange;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#description").on('blur', function(e) {
            var fname= $("#fullname").val();
            var trans= $("#trans").val();
            var desc=$("#description").val();
            if(fname=="" || trans=="" || desc=="" || !$("input:radio[name='testRadio']").is(":checked")){

            }else{
                $('#TWO').css('opacity', '1.25'); 
            }
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<form>
    <section id="ONE" class="section one active">
        <h2>Secion 1</h2>
        <div class="field-container">
            City: <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Full Name" required id="fullname"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Transport:
            <select class="required" required id="trans">
                <option value="" selected disabled>selected a value</option>
                <option>Car</option>
                <option>Buss</option>
                <option>Train</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Payment?
            <input type="radio" id="yes" name="testRadio" class="required" required /> Yes
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="testRadio" class="required" /> No
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Message:
            <textarea name="description" id="description" class="required"></textarea>
        </div>

    </section>
    <section id="TWO" class="section two">
        <h2>Secion 2</h2>
        <div class="field-container">
            Animal:
            <select class="required" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>selected a value</option>
                <option>Lion</option>
                <option>Rebbit</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Edible?
            <input type="radio" id="yes" name="testRadio" class="required" required /> Yes
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="testRadio" class="required" /> No
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="THREE" class="section three">
        <h2>Secion 3</h2>
        <div class="field-container">
            Name: <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Email: <input type="text" class="required" placeholder="Email" required />
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            Are you okay?
            <select class="required" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>selected a value</option>
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            When?
            <input type="checkbox" name="when1" value="Day"> Day
            <input type="checkbox" name="when2" value="Car"> Night
            <input type="checkbox" name="when3" value="Any"> Anytime<br>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            <input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="human" class="required"> I agree to the terms.<br>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="SUBMIT" class="section submit">
        <button type="button">Submit</button>
    </section>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to remove styles when user remove the value from input and textarea?

Comment: Onchange of input field write . 1)$("#fieldId").removeAttr("style"); to remove complete css 2) Particular style $("#fieldId").attr("attribute you want to change", "value you want to assign to attribute");